# Merge data jupyter variables. (Python)

Tags: python, list, jupyter

I have a barchart output. When i go to jupyter variables to see the exact x and y points as a list in dataviewer i get a problem.

I get many lists sorted by date instead of one total, i want to merge them. Or i mean aggregate them to see total X value for a certain Y value.

How can i do this, in Jupyter variable. Dataview.
Code is right and i get my output it´s just when i want to take a closer look in jupyter variables i have this problem that i can´t see total for a specific Y.

Thank you.

Comment: I reckon we need to know more about your setup. Do you get many `x-values` corresponding to a single `y-value`? If you don't give a small example of how your problem can be regenerated, it is very difficult for SO to provide you with an answer

Comment: Hi Yannis, yes thank you. When i run my code i get a figure output. I get a picture of a barchart that has the correct values. This barchart show the total amount of Volume for all prices and aggregate lists from different dates to show the total Volume per price. When i go to jupyter variable to see more exact positions the data is not aggregated, i can´t see the total per price anymore, it´s separated between dates into many lists. Exact what i see in the picture output i want to download and see in jupyter variable. How can i do this easy? Price on X axis, Volume on Y. thank you.

Comment: So to simplify, What i see in the barchart/picture output i want to see in jupyter variable. But why do the graphical/picture output aggregate but the jupyter variable list dosent?

Comment: How can i do this simple, just download graph output into jupyter variable.

Comment: I can't help you much on that. Please try to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to get help. Otherwise your question looks a bit blurry